# How to add 'name' and 'url' properties to the same tag?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I'm adding the schema.org Microdata to my website.

My HTML code is like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<span class="title">Name of the organization</span>
<a href="http://www.ABCCompany.com/">ABC Company</a>
</div>
```

Since the `itemprop` "url" and "name" of the Organization are all in the anchor tag. How can I indicate the both "url" and "name" `itemprop` on the same tag? Must I add extra `span` tag for this purpose?

I have tried searching some coding examples on this but cannot find any example to show the use of multiple `itemprop` on the same tag.

At the end, I want to have Microdata like this:

```
url="http://www.ABCCompany.com", name="ABC Company"
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to do it by nesting two elements. For example, you can nest a `<span>` inside the `<a>` and put the `itemprop="name"` on that:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.ABCCompany.com/">
        <span itemprop="name">ABC Company</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I find [this site](http://foolip.org/microdatajs/live/) handy for testing such things.

Comment: Is it really legal to nest itemprops like that? Have you seen any examples on that in the spec? The only examples on nested itemprops I have seen is when one of the itemprops is an itemtype and it starts a new itemscope.

Comment: Yes, of course it is legal. Why wouldn't it be? The algorithm in the spec recurses down into all sub-elements, except if there's an @itemscope on it.

Comment: @knut - An `itemprop` doesn't create a new scope like `itemscope` does. Each element type (`<a>`, `<span>`, etc) determines what part is extracted as the value for an attached `itemprop` attribute.

Comment: It seems extra span tag is unavoidable to assign two itemprop from the anchor tag.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a problem with google. The "rich snippets testing tool" indicates that when you mark an anchor tag as a url, the body of the tag is used as value rather than the href attribute. But nobody wants to display the url inside an anchor tag.

Comment: If you use the rich snippets testing tool, and you have itemprop='name' on the anchor, it will show the text inside the href as a linked item, so it looks like that works, and it almost seems like you got 'url' and 'name' in one fell swoop.

HOWEVER, if you look in Webmaster Tools, you will see that itemprop='name' is actually using the the URL for the name property.

In my experience, you need to have itemprop='url' on the anchor, and then a span inside the anchor with itemprop='name' on it. 

The testing tool is really deceiving.

Answer (score 0):

This also works and may look a bit easier to maintain:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <span class="title" itemprop="name">
    <a itemprop="url" href="http://www.ABCCompany.com/">ABC Company</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Google's support for schema.org and the [google structured data tester](http://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)  have improved considerably since the original question was posted. The code above validates correctly in it.

Answer (score -1):

The OP's original code now seems to work ok. As shown here:

> https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=http%3A%2F%2Fmercedes-benzhanoi.com.vn%2Fmercedes-ha-noi.auto%2Fgla-250-4matic.html

`<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<span class="title" itemprop="name">
<a itemprop="url" href="http://mercedes-benzhanoi.com.vn/mercedes-ha-noi.auto/gla-250-4matic.html">GLA 250 4MATIC</a></span>
</div>`